# Environment variable in Rails console and Pow

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rack-pow

I can't access env variables in the Rails console, while in the application they work.

In `.powenv` I have `export SENDGRID_PASSWORD="123"`

In `config/initializers/mail.rb` there is:

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :password => ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD']
}
```

So in the console when I type `UserMailer.welcome_mail.deliver` there is an error 'ArgumentError: SMTP-AUTH requested but missing secret phrase'. However from the application it sends the mail successfully.

How can I make the env variables available in the console?

Comment: Have you tried explicitly setting it in the console? SENDGRID_PASSWORD=123 && UserMailer.welcome_mail.deliver

Comment: No, it doesn't work this way too.

Comment: err I meant: `SENDGRID_PASSWORD=123 rails console`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your Rails console isn't able to access the environment variable because Pow passes information **from** the `.powenv` or `.powrc` file **into** Rails ... Rails doesn't read those files on its own.

In other words, you're setting the `ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD']` variable in the `.powenv` file, but that file is not being touched when you start the Rails console.

You'll need to set up a `before_filter` in your Application Controller that sets the `ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD']` (or come up with another, similar, way of reading in the `.powenv` file from within that `before_filter` in your Rails app).

Comment: "(or come up with another, similar, way of reading in the .powenv file from within that before_filter in your Rails app)" Yep, that would be fabulous... :) Any ideas?

Comment: I don't know if you'd want to actually read the `.powenv` file from your Rails app, since there could be other stuff in there that you don't want/need to reload each time.

Comment: If your `.powenv` file is super clean & each line is just setting environmental variables, then you might be able to read it in line by line within the `before_filter`. The `before_filter` could execute each line it reads out of the file. ... I'm pretty sure there are all sorts of wrong things going on with this idea, though ...

Comment: Yes, it's easy to read in .powenv line by line and only execute those lines which set env vars. Unfortunately those will not be available in the console (or in Rake) that way...

Answer (score 11):

try

```
. .powenv
```

then

```
rails c
```

(dot is a command to run script on current environment)

Answer (score 2):

For posterity, you can add something like this to either your environment.rb, development.rb, or an initializer (config/initializers/pow.rb) depending on what load order you want:

```
# Load pow environment variables into development and test environments
if File.exist?(".powenv")
  IO.foreach('.powenv') do |line|
    next if !line.include?('export') || line.blank?
    key, value = line.gsub('export','').split('=',2)
    ENV[key.strip] = value.delete('"\'').strip
  end
end
```