# Production server doesn't recognise environment variables set by Figaro gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have my Sendgrid password set in an external file (config/application.yml) which I set up with the Figaro gem. This works fine on my local machine, but on my server I am getting an error that no password has been set:

```
ArgumentError (SMTP-AUTH requested but missing secret phrase)
```

When I change the Sendgrid config to just the plaintext password it works fine, so I assume that Rails isn't recognising the environment variable. The weird thing is that when I go into `rails console production` and execute `puts ENV["SENDGRID_PASSWORD"]` it works fine.

Any ideas?

Here's my Sendgrid config:

```
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  :address              => "smtp.sendgrid.net",
  :port                 => 587,
  :user_name            => "chrislawrence",
  :password             => ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD'],
  :domain               => "lakecinema.net.au",
  :authentication       => :plain,
  :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```

Comment: I get the same behavior using an ENV variable, set in an initializer, within the subject (in mailer file) or body (in view for mailer).  It ignores the ENV variable I set, even after cache-clearing everything, restarting the server, etc.  Value is correct in Console, though.  Not using Figaro, so not limited to that.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and couldn't figure out why Rails thought I wasn't giving it a password.  Turns out I was defining `config.action_mailer.smtp_settings` in one file, and then adding key-value-combos to it in another file.  The problem is that I was using `merge` instead of `merge!` so my password was never making it into smtp_settings but instead into a temporary hash.

From this experience I learnt that the error message you're getting is ActionMailer's way of saying "Where's the password?"

So my guess is that your issue is the inverse of [Environment variable in Rails console and Pow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10527372/environment-variable-in-rails-console-and-pow), where an environment variable is working on the Rails server but not in Rails Console.  Try executing:

```
$ echo "$SENDGRID_PASSWORD"
```

and see what you get.  I have a feeling the Env variable is not set but that instead it's just a local variable in Rails Console.

Comment: Gotta same problem but in my case the reason was that I've used icorrect key (symbol) in production.rb configuration - `:user_password` instead of `:password`. My bad

Answer (score -1):

It should be :authentication       => 'plain'

Comment: This should be a comment