# How to access environment variables from .powenv in delayed job

Tags: ruby, delayed-job, rack-pow

I have some environment variables defined in .powenv.

```
export FOO=bar
```

A method that runs asynchronously via delayed_job needs to access this environment variable:

```
class A < ActiveRecord::Base
  def my_method
    B.new
  end
end
handle_asynchronously :my_method

class B
  def initialize
   puts ENV['FOO']
  end
end

a = A.find(1)
a.my_method
```

Is ENV['FOO'] available when my_method is called delayed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. Just run:

```
. .powenv
script/console delayed_job start
```

This answer led me to the right track:
[Environment variable in Rails console and Pow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10527372/environment-variable-in-rails-console-and-pow)

If you want to know what the dot command is for:
https://superuser.com/questions/46139/what-does-source-do